# IntelliJ IDEA auto insert space after choosing statement from suggested variants

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, phpstorm

I noticed that every time I made a choice in code completion suggested list I have to manually add a space after every statement, it's annoying. Want to automate this and try to find a solution in settings but nothing.

[image: PhpStorm code completion suggested list]]

[image: PhpStorm return statement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine here and behaviour depends on where `return` is used (tested in PhpStorm 2020.1.4 on Windows 10).

**1.** The space will inserted automatically after `return` completion in functions where IDE knowns that they can return non empty values, e.g.

- where return type is declared via PHPDoc or native PHP type;
- based on other/already present non-empty returns in function body.

**2.** If a function already declare that it will return `void` then `return;` will be inserted on completion (notice `;` at the end).

**3.** If no function return type is known in advance (e.g. you are writing first `return` and no return type declared) or other cases (e.g. return in include file -- a typical case is PHP config files (e.g. Laravel)) then no space will be inserted.

refs: [WI-51343](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51343), [WI-45793](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45793), [WI-45803](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45803).

---

Here are examples when IDE **will insert a space** after `return` keyword completion via completion popup:

A short demo video for one of the cases: https://recordit.co/U90Sx6PPTO

```php
function some1($a)
{
    if ($a) {
        return 22;
    }
    
    ret[COMPLETION]
}

function some2($a): string
{
    ret[COMPLETION]
}

/**
 * Some func.
 *
 * @param $a
 * @return string
 */
function some3($a)
{
    ret[COMPLETION]
}
```

Here IDE will insert `return;` (notice `;` at the end):

```php
/**
 * @param $a
 * @return void
 */
function some4($a)
{
    ret[COMPLETION]
}
```

---

Possible workaround if you ALWAYS want to have a space after `return` statement: just make [custom Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html) that will expand `r[TAB]` into `return [CARET]`.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, everything works as you described! I hope JetBrains will make a special option for this, as it seems to me in 99% of cases it is needed space after each select from suggested list (not only for Return statement)

Comment: @АлексейСеров 1) Examples? It is definitely possible that not all cases are covered yet. 2) Speaking in general: other person may prefer no space (if it's allowed there, of course) and have own code formatting style/rules.

Comment: After a few days of testing, I came to the conclusion that the spaces are quite correct. I found only one place where you have to constantly enter a space manually, where a value is assigned to a variable. In theory, IDE can determine that the variable is on a new line, which means it needs a space after selecting [Example new variable](https://ibb.co/T03JH5H).